# How to implement From trait for custom error types?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I am currently trying to write a custom error type for my CLI application. Now I want to write an implementation of the `From` trait so my custom error type can wrap all third party library errors that can occur.

The error enum:

```
#[derive(Debug)] // Allow the use of "{:?}" format specifier
pub enum CustomError {
    Git(git2::Error),
    Other
}
```

Now I want to implement the `From` Trait for the `git2::Error` from the `git2` library to use the `?` operator in my functions.

```
impl From<(git2::Error)> for CustomError {
    fn from(cause: git2::Error) -> Self {
        CustomError::Git(cause)
    }
}
```

But when I try to use my custom error to map an error like this:

```
let repo = Repository::open(path).map_err(|err| CustomError::Git)?;
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
the trait `std::convert::From<fn(git2::error::Error) -> error::CustomError {error::CustomError::Git}>` is not implemented for `error::CustomError `
```

Can anyone help me to understand why I am getting this error and how to solve this problem ?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've mixed up a whole bunch of concepts; let's see if we can walk through this together and hopefully clarify all of it.

The `git2` crate has its own error type, that you no doubt have discovered. Your definition of custom errors is fine as well.

The issue is twofold:

1. **Your implementation of `From<_>`**

`From<E>` allows you to transform a type from one type to another by providing the translation function (`from()`).

Your implementation of this was the following:

```
impl From<(git2::Error)> for CustomError {
    fn from(cause: git2::Error) -> Self {
        CustomError::Git(cause)
    }
}
```

Brackets in `rust` aren't added where they should not be, and this is precisely one of the cases where this is the case. By doing this, you've actually defined `From<(T)>`, not `From<T>`. That's mistake #1.

The correct implementation simply drops the brackets:

```
impl From<git2::Error> for CustomError {
    fn from(cause) -> Self {
        CustomError::Git(cause)
    }
}
```

2. **Your actual conversion**

Not an error per se, but a completely unnecessary operation as the `?` operator handles it for you. There is no need for the `map_err()`, and if there was you'd be using `into()` rather than hard-calling the type (which should already be defined as a type in your function).

Remember, the whole point of conversion traits is to define them *so you don't have to explicitly call them*.

A final "demo" version of the code in working order could look like this:

```
extern crate git2;
use git2::Repository;

#[derive(Debug)] // Allow the use of "{:?}" format specifier
pub enum CustomError {
    Git(git2::Error),
    Other
}
impl From<(git2::Error)> for CustomError {
    fn from(cause: git2::Error) -> Self {
        CustomError::Git(cause)
    }
}
fn test() -> Result<(), CustomError> {
    let path = "foo";
    let output = Repository::open(path)?;
    Ok(())
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very comprehensive answer and explanation. Now everything makes much more sense. Does this also works for converting errors in `ok_or` ?

Comment: It works whenever the compiler expects (due to types) your custom error type but starts off with something different - it checks if it can convert.